# Finding values in one vector that are between the values in another vector

Tags: r

I need some help finding the values in a vector that are between key values, non-inclusive.

For example, with the following vectors `x` and `y`

```
x <- c(2, 6, 10)
y <- c(7, 1, 9, 12, 4, 6, 3)
```

I'd like to find all the values in `y` that are between `x` but not equal to `x`, so that the result would be

```
list(y[y > 2 & y < 6], y[y > 6 & y < 10])
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 3
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 7 9
```

So in the above result,

- 3 and 4 are between 2 and 6
- 7 and 9 are between 6 and 10
- 12 is not between anything, so it is excluded
- 6 is equal to 6, so it too is excluded

I've been working on this for a little while now and I'm stumped. I'd show you the code but it's just plain ugly.

How can I quickly find the values in one vector what are between the values in another vector?

Comment: Why `12` is part of the result?

Comment: @DavidArenburg-  you're right, I updated it

Comment: Do you necessarily want it in a list? I.e., a result such as `[1] 7 9 4 3` won't work for you (or maybe sorted version of it)?

Comment: Does x always contain 3 numbers or could it have more than that?

Comment: @beginneR, I would guess it could contain any amount of values

Comment: I'd prefer a list so I know which values they are between

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
lapply(split(y[y > min(x) & y < max(x)], 
             findInterval(y[y > min(x) & y < max(x)], x)), 
       function(z) z[!z %in% x]) 
# $`1`
# [1] 4 3
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 7 9
```

Of course, it might be better to keep it DRY and subset "y" before splitting, for example, by using `between` (or `%between%`) from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
Z <- y[y %between% range(x) & !y %in% x]
split(Z, findInterval(Z, x))
# $`1`
# [1] 4 3
#
# $`2`
# [1] 7 9
```

---

#### Update

For reference, all three options so far are pretty fast:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(sample(100000, 20, FALSE))
y <- sample(100000, 100000, TRUE)

AM <- function(x, y) {
  Z <- y[y %between% range(x) & !y %in% x]
  split(Z, findInterval(Z, x))
}

DA <- function(x, y) {
  indx <- Map(function(x, z) x + seq_len(z), x[-length(x)], diff(x) - 1)
  lapply(indx, function(x) y[y %in% x])
}

user <- function(x, y) {
  m <- t(diff(sign(outer(x, y, "-"))) == 2)
  split((m*y)[m], col(m)[m])
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(AM(x, y), DA(x, y), user(x, y))
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#    AM(x, y)  22.58939  23.24731  26.29092  23.79639  25.64548 140.5610   100
#    DA(x, y) 149.46997 157.48534 162.47526 160.01823 164.74851 287.0808   100
#  user(x, y) 327.38835 437.44064 445.71955 446.65938 467.97784 637.3121   100
```

Comment: `findInterval` has a function argument?  This is news to me

Comment: @RichardScriven, No. `lapply` does.

Comment: Hey did you see Sven's answer down below?  Maybe we should run some comparisons.  His doesn't use a loop but is basically the same code as yours.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I don't quite understand your comment. My version that's comparable with his doesn't use a loop.

Comment: I was just referring to `lapply` in the first method.  No worries

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach

```
indx <- Map(function(x, z) x + seq_len(z), x[-length(x)], diff(x) - 1)
lapply(indx, function(x) y[y %in% x])
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 7 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Another variation. I think you could use `outer` and `sign`; going across the columns if there is a change from 1 to -1 then the `y` value is within the `x` range (that is, where consecutive columns sum to zero). The loop to extract the values is a bit messy though.

**EDIT** 
@flodel offered a nice alternative in the comments

```
m <- t(diff(sign(outer(x, y, "-"))) == 2)
split((m*y)[m], col(m)[m])
```

Original

```
(o <- sign(outer(y, x, "-")))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1   -1
# [2,]   -1   -1   -1
# [3,]    1    1   -1
# [4,]    1    1    1
# [5,]    1   -1   -1
# [6,]    1    0   -1
# [7,]    1   -1   -1

lapply(1:(length(x)-1), function(i) y[o[,i] + o[,i+1]==0])
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 7 9
```

Comment: A nice variant would be `m <- t(diff(sign(outer(x, y, "-"))) == 2); split((m*y)[m], col(m)[m])`

Comment: That's good @flodel, I couldn't see a nice way to extract - ty

Answer (score 0):

```
Try:

z =list()
for(j in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
    v=NULL
    for(i in 1:length(y))   
       if(y[i]>x[j] && y[i]<x[j+1]) 
            v[length(v)+1]=y[i]
    z[[length(z)+1]] = v
}
z
[[1]]
[1] 4 3

[[2]]
[1] 7 9
```