# Python way to find values in one list that fall in-between the values of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Working with some research data and trying to find a good Pythonic way to determine if the values in one list fall in between the values of another list. Each line of each data file contains a sequential list of years that indicate a year in which a significant value was found on the left, and another sequential list of years that indicate a year where a tied value was found on the right, separated by a pipe character and spaces between each year.

Example: `1950 1955 1960 1977|1957 1958 1959 1966 1970 1975 1980 2015`

So, in the example above the year 1950 has no tie, but the year 1955 was tied by years 1957, 1958 and 1959. The year 1960 was tied by 1966 and 1970. The year 1977 was tied by 1980 and 2015.

These lists are being dynamically created based on the evaluation of changing data, so on any given iteration when processing this data, the list on the left or right side of the pipe character may have more or less items.

When processing these lists, the years on the left are given a value of one, but the years on the right must be assigned a weighted value based on how often they occur as a tie with the year in the list on the left side of the pipe character.

The weight of value assigned to the tied years on the right need to be decremented in a reciprocal fashion. For example, the year 1957 would be assigned a weighted value of 0.5, the year 1958 would be given a weighted value of 0.33, and the year 1959 would only be valued at 0.25. Then, the next range of tied years would be greater than 1960 and less than 1977, and starting with 1966 that would in turn start again with a weighted value of 0.5.

Looking on Stack Overflow and found something similar to what I am trying to do, but there is no "between()" function in Python:

[Finding values in one vector that are between the values in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773622/finding-values-in-one-vector-that-are-between-the-values-in-another-vector)

Is there a Pythonic way to make such a comparison, and dynamically assign values to the tied years on the right based on how they fall in-between the significant years on the left just using Python 2.7.5 and no additional add-on libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem can be decomposed into 2 steps:

- Calculate ranges for each year on the left.
- Calculate weights for each year on the right.

Python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) built-in and list / dictionary comprehensions should be sufficient.

Below is an example implementation. I have included intermediary output to help you understand what is happening at each stage.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

mystr = '1950 1955 1960 1977|1957 1958 1959 1966 1970 1975 1980 2015'

lsts = [list(map(int, x.split())) for x in mystr.split('|')]

# [[1950, 1955, 1960, 1977], [1957, 1958, 1959, 1966, 1970, 1975, 1980, 2015]]

def ranger(x1, x2, lst):
    return [i for i in lst if i in range(x1, x2)]

d = {i: ranger(i, j, lsts[1]) for i, j in \
     zip_longest(lsts[0], lsts[0][1:], fillvalue=lsts[1][-1]+1)}

# {1950: [], 1955: [1957, 1958, 1959], 1960: [1966, 1970, 1975], 1977: [1980, 2015]}

w = {k: [1/(i+2) for i in range(len(v))] if v else [] for k, v in d.items()}

# {1950: [],
#  1955: [0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25],
#  1960: [0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25],
#  1977: [0.5, 0.3333333333333333]}
```

Comment: Wow! I think that is exactly what I am looking for. I'll stitch it in to my current program, and let you know how it goes. I have been working on this for countless hours, and the client dropped this in kinda last minute. When you stare at trees for that long it gets hard to see the forest and the tree right in front of you. Thank you for your help and a fresh set of eyes on the problem. :)

Comment: Implemented this in the code and tested, but getting zeros instead of decimal values. Ran the code as a stand alone outside my program and returned the same.

Comment: This is the current output: [[1950, 1955, 1960, 1977], [1957, 1958, 1959, 1966, 1970, 1975, 1980, 2015]]
1960 [1966, 1970, 1975]
1977 [1980, 2015]
1955 [1957, 1958, 1959]
1950 []
1960 [0, 0, 0]
1977 [0, 0]
1955 [0, 0, 0]
1950 []
Any advise? Running Python 2.7. Is there something I need to import so the math works?

Comment: I ran this just now (literally copying & pasting from here), it works fine. BUT i'm using python 3.6. there may be some function which is incompatible with 2.7 but nto sure which. probably can be easily fixed if you figure out which bit.

Comment: Interestingly, if I change 1/(i+2) to 1/(i+1) the dictionary w yields: [(1960, [1, 0, 0]), (1977, [1, 0]), (1955, [1, 0, 0]), (1950, [])]

Comment: You can test 3.6 on https://repl.it/languages/python3, but that might not help you.

Comment: Thank you. Just saw your comment. Wonder what about 2.7 prevents this from working? Are you importing anything other than the 3.6 itertools lib?

Comment: No, I'm not.. find out which bit isn't working by comparing print statements to the ones i've put up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to stick with 2.7 on this. Too much red tape to try and get 3.6 on the server at work. Project will never complete on time trying to go that route. Thanks again for your help. I may still be able to incorporate the logic without the comprehension magic, just more code. You still really helped me see the tree right in front. :)

Comment: Definetly will try some print statements. Thanks :)

Comment: Just so you know I switched the shebang to 3.5 and works like a charm on my laptop, so definitely a version thing.

Comment: This worked perfectly in 3.5 Python and will work in 2.7 Python, but looks like you have to make the syntax "1/(i+2)"  read "1.0/(i+2)" so that it will output the division to a float. Otherwise you just get zeros. Solved my problem! Thank you jpp! :)